# Solution of the nonlinear differential equation $yy'-x^2{y'}^2=0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Find general solution of the equation $$yy'-x^2{y'}^2=0.\tag{1}$$

I found the solutions $y=c_1$ and $y=c_2e^{-1/x}$.

What is a general solution?
Is it $y=c_1+c_2e^{-1/x}$?

Comment: You are done :)

Comment: With the purpose to explore particular solutions maybe the factorization of the differential equation is useful, since note that in each term was the factor $y'$, thus maybe is useful to integrate from $$y'\cdot(y-x^2y')=0$$ these differential equations $y'=0$ or $y-x^2y'=0$ if as was your purpose  you want to know particular solutions to build from those a general solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Let's check:

$y=c_1+c_2e^{-1/x}$

$yy' = (c_1+c_2e^{-1/x})c_2x^{-2}e^{-1/x} = c_1c_2x^{-2}e^{-1/x} + c_2^2x^{-2}e^{-2/x}$

$x^2y'^2 = c_2^2x^{-2}e^{-2/x}$

$\Rightarrow yy' \ne x^2y'^2$

(unless, of course, $c_1=0$ or $c_2=0$)

In general a NLDE does not allow you to superpose individual solutions to get a general solution - this only works for LDEs.

Comment: You are right. Thank you. All right, we can't say anything about general solution of a NLDE?